# Build own Object-functions via vanilla js

Tags: javascript

how to build own functions to call them on defined objects via pure javascript?
Jquery is performing like this and I want to know how. Here is a small sample which shows what I want to do:

```js
doc = {
  qS: function(selector) {
     return document.querySelector(selector);
  }
};
    
var me = doc.qS('#id');
me.qS('span').innerText = 'Changed!';
```

```html
<div id="id"><span>Test</span></div>
```

Comment: jQuery is [open source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery). Be warned that jQuery's way of doing this is slightly convoluted. Separately: Work through some JavaScript tutorials and you should start to get an idea how to do this sort of thing (hint: jQuery is a **wrapper**, it doesn't return the result of `querySelectorAll` or `querySelector` directly).

Comment: It's called prototypal inheritance. At least that's the inheritance model that JS uses, and it is a very common approach, though not the only one. It is what jQuery uses. [MDN Inheritance and the prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)

Comment: Thanks @squint maybe you can give me an example?

Comment: It's an example, not exactly what i want to do @torazaburo

Comment: I should mention [picoQuery](http://picoquery.com) here. With picoQuery you can build a mini-jQuery by selecting which features and methods of the jQuery API you want it to support. This way you can have a very small library taylormade for your "jQuery" needs

Comment: @rosell.dk thats a good one. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```
doc = {
  qS: function(selector) {
     return document.querySelector(selector);
  }
};

var me = doc.qS('#id');
me.qS('span').innerText = 'Changed!';
```

After you call `doc.qS('#id')`, `me` contains a DOM element, which has no `q5` method defined. If you want to chain calls a la jQuery, you will have to build some more machinery, such as a wrapper around DOM elements:

```
function DOM(elt) {
  return {
    qS(selector)        { return DOM(elt.querySelector(selector)); },
    set innerText(text) { elt.innerText = text; },
    get innerText()     { return elt.innerText; }
  };
}
```

Now you can do:

```
DOM(document).qS('#id').qS('span').innerText = "foo";
```

You could instead implement DOM as a constructor (calling it via `new DOM`), and specify methods such as `qS` on its prototype, or implement DOM as an ES6 class, but those are really implementation details.

However, to handle calls to methods such as `querySelectorAll`, which return lists of things, you'll have to expand this to handle multiple elements (which is what jQuery does). Before long, you'll have a less-capable version of jQuery or a lightweight version of jQuery such as zepto, which you'll have to maintain yourself, for questionable benefit.

If all you want is an alias for `querySelector`, although generally considered bad practice, you could do

```
Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement, 'qS', {
  value(selector) { return this.querySelector(selector); }
});
```

But now you have another thing to maintain and explain, and it's probably not worth the trouble.

A lot of people like the chaining style, and it's fair to say it was made popular by jQuery. But other people dislike it. I guess you could say it was a bit of a fad, and now going out of fashion somewhat. You might as well just write

```
var id = document.querySelector('#id');
var span = id.querySelector('span');
span.textContent = 'Changed!';
```

Of course if that's all you wanted to do, you could just write `querySelector('#id span')` to start with.

You could also consider **why** you feel the need to pick out DOM elements and do things with them, such as adding styles, maybe? Many jQuery programs are contorted tangles of code that traverses the DOM in various weird ways and adds and removes and modifies elements. A great deal of what you see people using jQuery to do can be accomplished with the judicious use of CSS. With less JS code needing to walk around the DOM and manipulate it, comes less need for syntactic sugar such as the chaining that made jQuery famous.

If you choose a modern framework which provides some kind of templating language, you can reduce the amount of direct DOM manipulation you need to do in JS to nearly zero.